# How to set Notepad++ GUI text to a bigger font?

Tags: fonts, zooming, notepad-plus-plus

I installed Notepad++ on my Ubuntu 22.04 via terminal

```
sudo snap install notepad-plus-plus
```

However, the text of the UI buttons, tabs, dropdown menues (not the opened file text), is too small compared with others UI, apps in my OS.

[image]

So, is there a way to increase the font size of UI buttons, tabs, dropdown menues?

I have searched on the internet but I can't find a way to solve this problem for Ubuntu (there are some methods suggested for Windows).

What I expect to find is a plugin for Notepad++ or an external app that increase the font size of a selected app.

Can anybody point me some of these ones, if any of them exist?

Comment: How was the app installed?

Comment: via terminal `sudo snap install notepad-plus-plus`. question updated

Comment: Since it is a snap app probably not. Snap apps are containerized so changes by outside sources do not apply. You could try and ask the app maintainers if they have a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by switching to [Notepadqq](https://notepadqq.com/s/) that is pretty much like Notepad++ but with bigger UI fonts.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install notepadqq -y
```